# Infinite graphs isomorphic to their line graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory, graph-theory

The only finite connected graphs $G$ that are isomorphic to their [line graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) $L(G)$ are the [cycle graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph) $C_n$ (see [this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LineGraph.html) for example).

There are connected countable graphs that are isomorphic to their line graph:

- $G=(\omega,E)$ where $E=\{\{k,k+1\}: k\in\omega\}$;
- $G=(\mathbb{Z},E)$ where $E=\{\{k,k+1\}: k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Note that in the second graph, all vertices have degree 2, which makes it into a kind of "infinite cycle". (An interesting side question would be whether these are the only connected countable graphs (up to isomorphism) that are isomorphic to their line graph.)

**Question.** Is there a connected graph $G=(V,E)$ with $V$ uncountable such that $G\cong L(G)$?

Comment: That's right - > just edited

Comment: Regarding the side question, the complete graph with a countable number of vertices is isomorphic to its line graph.

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe your real question is about graphs *of bounded degree*?

Comment: @TimothyChow: It is not hard to see that if $G\cong L(G)$ and $G$ has a vertex of degree at least 3, then $G$ has a vertex of degree at least $n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  Basically, start with a graph with a vertex of degree 3 and one more connected edge and then iterate the operation $L$; all the graphs obtained from this must embed in $G$, but they have vertices of arbitrarily high degree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note first that $L$ is naturally an endofunctor on the category of graphs and injective graph-homomorphisms that commutes with filtered colimits.  Let $G$ be any graph such that there is an embedding $i:G\to L(G)$.  This gives rise to an embedding $L(i):L(G)\to L(L(G))$, an embedding $L(L(i)):L(L(G))\to L(L(L(G)))$, and so on.  Let $L^\omega(G)$ be the colimit of $G\to L(G)\to L(L(G))\to \dots$.  Since $L$ commutes with filtered colimits, there are canonical isomorphisms  $$L(L^\omega(G))\cong L(\varinjlim(G\to L(G)\to\dots))\cong \varinjlim( L(G)\to L(L(G))\to\dots)\cong L^\omega(G).$$

Furthermore, if $G$ is connected, so is $L^\omega(G)$, and if $G$ is infinite, $L^\omega(G)$ has the same cardinality as $G$.  Thus to get a connected graph of a given infinite cardinality isomorphic to its line graph, it suffices to give a connected graph $G$ of that cardinality that embeds in $L(G)$.  But this is easy; for instance, complete graphs work.  In fact, any connected graph whose cardinality $\kappa$ has uncountable cofinality works, since such a graph must contain a vertex of degree $\kappa$, and thus $L(G)$ contains a clique of size $\kappa$.

Comment: A connected graph of cardinality $\aleph_\omega$ does not necessarily have a vertex of degree $\aleph_\omega$.

Comment: bof: Thanks, corrected.  @Carl: $L(G)$ is not complete, but it contains a complete subgraph of the same size (all the edges containing some particular vertex).